# How to implement File explore design for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am trying to implement File Explore design for iPhone where user can ***browse the files inside my app***, so is there any sample ref available for same.

Comment: thats good, but I dont think you can explore files from your app in iphone unless the iphone is jail broken.

Comment: I need to show the file explore which are saved only in application folder not on iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only have to take a look into the [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)-Class which is able to list files in folders, get attributes of files, create/delete files, .... Inside the class-reference you can also find some sample-codes.

some extra-snippets:

how to get the app-folder:

```
NSString *appFolder = NSHomeDirectory();
```

how to list files in a specified folder:

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; //App-Documents-Folder
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *contentList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR LISTING FILES: %@",[error description]);
    return;
}
for (NSString *s in contentList)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
}
```

The only thing you have to do is to bind this information to a tableview or sth else.